# Cython C++ tutorial: Symbol not found

Tags: python, c++, vector, cython, setup.py

I am trying the Cython tutorial which uses a C++ vector (https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html). It compiles fine, but when I import the module I receive `Symbol not found: __ZTINSt8ios_base7failureB5cxx11E`

```
# distutils: language=c++

from libcpp.vector cimport vector

def primes(unsigned int nb_primes):
    cdef int n, i
    cdef vector[int] p
    p.reserve(nb_primes)  # allocate memory for 'nb_primes' elements.

    n = 2
    while p.size() < nb_primes:  # size() for vectors is similar to len()
        for i in p:
            if n % i == 0:
                break
        else:
            p.push_back(n)  # push_back is similar to append()
        n += 1

    # Vectors are automatically converted to Python
    # lists when converted to Python objects.
    return p
```

My `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import os

os.environ["CC"] = "gcc-10"
os.environ["CXX"] = "gcc-10"

ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        "test",
        ["test.pyx"],
        language = "c++"
    )
]

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize(ext_modules, annotate=True),
)
```

What have I done wrong?

**Edit:** By removing the `os.environ` settings and setting language level to 3 (instead of the default, 2 ?!!) I was able to fix this. Thanks to everyone who helped.

Comment: How did you export your C++ function? Is it declared `extern "C"`?

Comment: The function `primes` isn’t a C++ function. It’s a Python function. And that’s not the issue. I can’t import the file at all!

Comment: According to the error message, your environment is missing a C++11 function. I would suggest updating your python packages you are using. An out-of-date package can cause such an error.

Comment: The only non-builtin package I'm using is Cython, which I have just reinstalled. Still no luck.

Comment: In os.environ["CXX"] = "gcc-10"it should be g++-10, otherwise not all needed libraries are linked.